# Laravel 9 doesn't do post action to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forms, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I encounter a problem. Whenever I do a form request Laravel gives me a JSON response of form but doesn't post to MySQL. I did create another Laravel web application but then Laravel version was 8 and I can upload my data to MySQL. I checked my code billion times but I can't seem to difference and I don't get wht it doesnt post.

// PostController@store

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all();
        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'meta_description' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'posted_by' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'like' => 'required',
            'dislike' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $imageName = $request->image->store('public');
        }else{
            return 'No';
        }

        $slug2 = Str::slug($request->title, '-');

        $post = new Post;
        $post->meta_description = $request->input('meta_description');
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->status = $request->status;
        $post->slug = $slug2;
        $post->posted_by = 'Onur Sedef';
        $post->image = $imageName;
        $post->like = "1";
        $post->dislike = '0';
        $post->save();
    }
```

//database migration

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->mediumText('meta_description', 150);
            $table->string('slug', 120)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->nullable();
            $table->integer('posted_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->integer('like')->nullable();
            $table->integer('dislike')->nullable();
        });
```

// JSON response

```json
{
  "_token": "I6v9cZmUaPKQsCINj6CvNcJYqEU6ERbEj6P9tTyk",
  "title": "title",
  "meta_description": "meta",
  "body": "<h1><u>Heading Of Message</u></h1>\r\n<h4>Subheading</h4>\r\n<p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>List item one</li>\r\n<li>List item two</li>\r\n<li>List item three</li>\r\n<li>List item four</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n<p>Thank you,</p>\r\n<p>John Doe</p>",
  "category": "Deneme",
  "tag": "tag",
  "status": "1",
  "image": {
    
  }
}
```

Edit: Problem isn't version of Laravel, but still I can't seem to find it.

Comment: What happens when you remove `return $request->all();`, check for any error messages/logs.

Comment: I'm using virtual host so I don't know how to check for error messages etc. and when I remove `return` it's just go to index route which is `PostController@index`.

Comment: Since you have no redirect in your controller action, I believe you might be failing validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after another few hours I found out that the problem is in `PostController@store` and it doesn't post to MySQL because empty fields. Laravel sees `$post->posted_by = "Onur Sedef";` as empty field and because it is a required field it don't post to MySQL. I had a error catcher in my `index.blade.php` file but it was belonged to an old version of Laravel so it didn't worked that's why I struggled so much. After changing `session()->has('error)` to  `($errors->any())` I catched that error. Thanks everyone for their precious comments.